# Using options object in Vuetify 2.x v-data-table

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am using Vue component `v-data-table` from Vuetify 2.x.

```
<template>
    <v-data-table
        :hide-default-footer="hideFooter || false"
        :ref="modelName + 'Table'"
        :id="modelName + 'Table'"
        :value="selectedList"
        @input="$emit('update:selectedList', $event)"
        :headers="dataTable.headers"
        :items="collection"
        :showSelect="showSelect || false"
        item-key="id"
        class="elevation-1"
        :options.sync="topicsDataTable.options">
   </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                topicsDataTable: {
                    headers: [
                        { text: 'Topic', value: 'title', sortable: false },
                        { text: 'Current Interval', value: 'current_revision_interval', sortable: false },
                        { text: 'Interval Benchmark', value: 'interval_benchmark', sortable: true },
                        { text: 'Add Date', value: 'created_at', sortable: true },
                    ],
                    options: {
                        sortBy: 'interval_benchmark'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Per [the documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/), it states that an options prop can be passed to the component to control column sorting, etc.

```
{
  page: number
  itemsPerPage: number
  sortBy: string[]
  sortDesc: boolean[]
  groupBy: string[]
  groupDesc: boolean[]
  multiSort: boolean
  mustSort: boolean
}
```

However when I pass the `options` object that includes the `sortBy` property in the above sample it gives me the following error:

> this.options.sortBy.findIndex is not a function

How is this not being passed correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like **sortBy** prop is waiting for `string[]`, not just one `string`.

Try this:

```
...
data() {
    return {
        topicsDataTable: {
            headers: [
                ...
            ],
            options: {
                sortBy: ['interval_benchmark']
            }
        }
    }
}
...
```